# Use enum in angular to select drop in edit menu item

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I want to implement select menu which uses enum data to display data and saved number based on the selected String:

```
export enum MerchantStateType {
  being_set_up = 1,
  live_for_processing = 2,
  trading_suspended = 3,
  account_suspended = 4,
}

export const MerchantStateType2LabelMapping = {
  [MerchantStateType.being_set_up]: "Being set up",
  [MerchantStateType.live_for_processing]: "Live for processing",
  [MerchantStateType.trading_suspended]: "Trading suspended",
  [MerchantStateType.account_suspended]: "Account suspended",
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="form-group state_raw">
    <label for="state_raw">State</label>
    <select class="custom-select" name="state_raw" [(ngModel)]="merchant.state_raw" id="state_raw" required>
      <!--<option selected></option>-->
      <option [value]="stateType" *ngFor="let stateType of stateTypes">{{ MerchantStateType2LabelMapping[stateType] }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

When page is loaded `merchant.state_raw` is loaded with value for example `2` How I can translate it from value to String into the select menu and save it again as number?

Comment: What you're doing [seems already correct](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-andedd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). What is the issue?